# Лаги при переключении рабочих столов win10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Добрый день, уважаемые. Столкнулся с проблемой, что на win10 при переключении между рабочими столами (по ctrl+win+Right например), происходит переход, но с жутким дёрганием. Как будто кадрами. Когда появилась проблема - не заметил. Пробовал откатывать драйвера видеокарты, не помогло, обновление их тоже не помогло.
Видеокарта вообще не нагружена.

[Запись видео (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FCKbq0kXYw&feature=youtu.be)

Прошу помочь решить проблему, или натолкнуть на ее решение :)

Comment: Часом программа для майнинга на видеокарте не висит в фоне? Было подобное, когда приятель вирусный майнер подхватил.

Comment: Видео недоступно

Comment: @viktor-tomilov, забыл открыть доступ, уже открыл

Comment: нет, ничего подобного не висит, антивирус стоит.

Comment: Что за видеокарта? Как меняется загрузка CPU во время переключения? На Fall.Creators Update обновлялись?

Comment: Radeon 280X, нагрузка на CPU меняется, незначительно если очень быстро переключать. У меня Превьюшка, 17025

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69423/discussion-between--and-viktor-tomilov).